# I am not able to access variable value of another class in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have a class A and class B. and class B extends from Class A.

In the class A I have this statement.

```
JCombobox namecombo; 

    JButton btnPrint = new JButton("Print");
    btnPrint.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            CreateInvoiceTable op = new CreateInvoiceTable();
            op.invoicetable();
            insertingBillNoIntoDatabase();
            String custname =namecombo.getSelectedItem().toString();
            MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat(custname);
            MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("SAHA TRADERS");
            try {
                table.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header,footer);
            } catch (PrinterException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            while(model_table.getRowCount()>0) {
                model_table.removeRow(0);
            }

            itemcombo.setSelectedIndex(0);



        }
    });
```

I selected the name from *combobox* and hit a button(print) to execute class B.

In the class B.

```
public void invoicetable() {

    String name = Invoice.namecombo.getSelectedItem().toString();

    System.out.println(name); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CreateInvoiceTable a = new CreateInvoiceTable();
    a.invoicetable();
}
}
```

Now when I print it. It just prints the first value of *comboBox* not the
 selected one.

Comment: You need to provide some more code.

Comment: @Aris_Kortex okay

Comment: now i don't understand what to add more....

Comment: i am populating namecombo from database

Comment: i hope you guys are understanding the problem.

Comment: Why are you extending class A from class B?

Comment: @Aris_Kortex to access the value of variable of class A in class B

Comment: I'm writing an answer.

Comment: @Aris_Kortex okay go ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem here stems from a poor knowlegde of instance variable access.

Supposing that you have instantiated your `ClassA` object somewhere and you start to operate it. At some point the value of the `JCombobox` is going to be changed. This means that the state of it still resides within the instance of `ClassA`.

In your print method, you create a new instance of `CreateInvoiceTable` on which you invoke the `invoicetable` table. While you expect that this will effectively give you the power to access the value of the `JCombobox` that resides within the `ClassA` object, this is not the case.

Upon instantiating the extending class you'll effectively create a new instance of it, which means a new `JCombobox`. This explains why when invoking `getSelectedItem` within the context of the second class the returned value is incorrect.

I assume that this line `String custname =namecombo.getSelectedItem().toString();` effectively returns the correct value, which would have a clue for you to resolve this.

Now my best suggestion here is to simply stop extending classA from classB. Since your `invoicetable` method will only print out a name a bill, just pass the name value as a parameter within this.

I would also suggest to check on variable access and inheritance, as it seems that these notions are confused in you mind.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @KaranMalhotra nice. As suggested, above have a good read up on how inheritance and member access works. Also please go ahead upvote and make this the accepted answer.